# updating datatable from JSF ajax call

Tags: primefaces

I am using PF 3.1.1, JSF 2.0.

I have a datatable with a column for selectBooleanCheckBox. When the user selects the row I want the checkbox to be checked and when user checks the checkbox the row should be selected.

I am making a ajax call on selectBooleanCheckBox, it updates the selectionArray in backing bean but the results are not shown on screen.

Here is the code -

```
<p:dataTable id="mylist" value="#{myController.selectedLists}"
                                         selection="#{myController.myArray}"
                                         selectionMode="multiple"
                                         var="item"
                                         rows="5"
                                         rowKey="#{item.id}"
                                         sortBy="#{item.name}"
                                         sortOrder="ascending"
                                         >
                                <p:ajax event="rowSelect" 
                                        listener="#{myController.onSelectList}"
                                        update="mylist"/>
                                <p:column style="width: 20px;" id="gs">
                                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="booId"
                                                             value="#{item.booVal}">
                                        <f:ajax execute="@this"
                                                listener="#{myController.booValListener}"
                                                render="mylist"/>
                                        <f:attribute name="item" value="#{item}" />
                                    </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                                </p:column> </p:datatable>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Does the checkbox/radiobutton selection method not work for you? Check out the showcase demo for that feature: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/datatableRowSelectionRadioCheckbox.jsf

Now to your problem: In the past I've had problems updating a datatable after an ajax request.  Unless they've addressed this since primefaces 3.0, it is not possible to update the datatable directly, you have to wrap a panelGroup around it and update the panelGroup. For example:

```
<h:panelGroup id="panel">
     <p:dataTable id="mylist" value="#{myController.selectedLists}"
                                     selection="#{myController.myArray}"
                                     selectionMode="multiple"
                                     var="item"
                                     rows="5"
                                     rowKey="#{item.id}"
                                     sortBy="#{item.name}"
                                     sortOrder="ascending"
                                     >
           <p:ajax event="rowSelect" 
                                    listener="#{myController.onSelectList}"
                                    update="panel"/>
           ...
     </p:dataTable>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Try that and see how it goes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, If I have rowSelectListener in the datatable then the checkbox selection does not work. That is the reason I am using selectBooleanCheckbox.

Comment: Thanks again. Actually I was trying to update the datatable from AJax event of JSF which does not have a update attribute. I did it as <f:ajax execute="@this"
   listener="#{myController.onBooListener}"
   render="@form"/>
   <f:attribute name="item" value="#{item}" />